# Issue with edittext in TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I am trying to configure a simple form . I have 3 editexts and after a user ends input, i want to show up checked icon if it's valid (and goes to the next field) and error if not and the user can correct.

My main issue is I can only input 1 character and then it shows me or error or checked icon and it goes to the next field.

What do I do wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public class ConTct extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener{

    Button mButton;
    EditText mFullName, mEmail, mDialZone, mPhone;
    static WebView mWebView;
    static ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    EditText mBrokerId, mIP, mAreaPhonePrefix, mLastName, mPassWord, mCampaign, mSubCampaign, mCountryID, mCity, mAdress, mIsDemo;

    private String inputText;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.contct);

        registerViews();


    }//oncreate()


        private void registerViews(){
    mFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName);
    mFullName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(hasFocus){
                //do nothing
            }else{
                if(!Validation.hasText(mFullName)){
                    mFullName.setError("You have to input at least 3 characters");
                    mFullName.requestFocus();
                }else{
                    mFullName.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.llgr, 0);
                    mFullName.clearFocus();

                    mEmail.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

    mEmail.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(hasFocus){
                //do nothing
            }else{

                if(!Validation.isEmailAddress(mEmail, true)){
                    mEmail.setError("wrong email");
                    mEmail.requestFocus();
                }else{
                    mEmail.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.llgr, 0);
                    mEmail.clearFocus();

                    mPhone.requestFocus();
                }

            }
        }
    });
    mPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);

    mPhone.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(hasFocus){
                //do nothing
            }else{

                if(!Validation.isPhoneNumber(mPhone, true)){
                    mPhone.setError("wrong email");
                    mPhone.requestFocus();
                }else{
                    mPhone.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.llgr, 0);
                    mPhone.clearFocus();


                }

            }

        }
    });

        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SubmitRegisterButton);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    private void submitForm() {
        // Submit your form here. your form is valid
        Toast.makeText(this, "Submitting form...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private boolean checkValidation() {
        boolean ret = true;

        if (!Validation.hasText(mFullName)){
            ret = false;

        }

        if (!Validation.isEmailAddress(mEmail, true)){
            ret = false;
        }

        if (!Validation.isPhoneNumber(mPhone, true)){
            ret = false;
        }

        if (!Validation.hasText(mPhone)){

            ret = false;

        }

        return ret;
    }//checkValidation


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if ( checkValidation () ){
            submitForm();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThanksZuser.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            //send to our crm
            grabURL(myURL);
        }else
            Toast.makeText(ConTct.this, "Form contains error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}//ConTct.class
```

Validation class:

```
package com.Signals4Trading.push.android;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import android.widget.EditText;

public class Validation {

    // Regular Expression
    // you can change the expression based on your need
    private static final String EMAIL_REGEX = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    //  private static final String PHONE_REGEX = "\\d{3}-\\d{7}";
    //  private static final String PHONE_REGEX = "(\\d{3})-(\\d{3})-(\\d{4})";
    private static final String PHONE_REGEX = "([0-9-( )]+)";


    // Error Messages
    private static final String REQUIRED_MSG = "Invalid name. You have to input at least 3 characters";
    private static final String EMAIL_MSG = "Invalid email";
    private static final String PHONE_MSG = "Invalid number";

    // call this method when you need to check email validation
    public static boolean isEmailAddress(EditText editText, boolean required) {
        return isValid(editText, EMAIL_REGEX, EMAIL_MSG, required);
    }

    // call this method when you need to check phone number validation
    public static boolean isPhoneNumber(EditText editText, boolean required) {
        return isValid(editText, PHONE_REGEX, PHONE_MSG, required);
    }

    /*
    // return true if the input field is valid, based on the parameter passed
    public static boolean isValid(EditText editText, String regex, String errMsg, boolean required) {

        String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        // clearing the error, if it was previously set by some other values
        editText.setError(null);

        // text required and editText is blank, so return false
        if ( required && !hasText(editText) ) return false;

        // pattern doesn't match so returning false
        if (required && !Pattern.matches(regex, text)) {
            editText.setError(errMsg);
            return false;
        };

        if ( required && !hasNumber(editText)) return false;

        return true;
    }
     */

    // return true if the input field is valid, based on the parameter passed
    public static boolean isValid(EditText editText, String regex, String errMsg, boolean bRequired) {
        // text required and editText is blank, so return false
        String sText = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        // clearing the error, if it was previously set by some other values
        editText.setError(null);
        if (sText.length() == 0) {
            if (bRequired) {
                editText.setError("*Field required");
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // filled field
            // pattern doesn’t match so returning false
            if (!Pattern.matches(regex, sText)) {
                editText.setError(errMsg);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // check the input field has any text or not
    // return true if it contains text otherwise false
    public static boolean hasText(EditText editText) {

        String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        editText.setError(null);

        // length less that 3 means there is no text
        if (text.length() <= 3 && text.length() > 12) {
            editText.setError(REQUIRED_MSG);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static boolean hasNumber(EditText editText) {

        String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        editText.setError(null);

        // length less that 6 and more than 11 means not available
        if (text.length() <= 6 && text.length() >= 11) {
            editText.setError(PHONE_MSG);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}//Validation
```

Answer (score 1):

> My main issue is I can only input 1 character and then it shows me or
>   error or checked icon and it goes to the next field.

Issue is:

You are calling the validation method in onTextChanged. So its going in hasText method, determines there is less than 3 characters, and shows error. In your case, its better to implement using `OnFocusChangeListener`

**Example:**

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            //do nothing
        }else {
            // validate here and show error if invalid and set focus to this element again using requestFocus.
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh thank you! I edit my text and tried to do what you explain. now the cursor is making "ping-pong" between the first edittext and the second..After i finish enter some text, i want to go to the 2nd field and the cursor is going from one field to another without me to do something. What do I do wrong?

Comment: @user3111349 I didn't get what you are saying.

Comment: It doesn't work as it supposed to.. Is my edit code looks ok? Or do I do something wrong?

Comment: @use please explain what you mean

Comment: I'd like to send you a screenshot, it will be more clear but I can't add a picture because I do not have enough reputation or something. What I am trying to explain is when I finish typing on the first field and want to go on the second field, the cursor is going to the second field, coming back to the first, coming back to the second, etc.. without me taping on anything. so what is wrong in the code i edit?

Comment: @user3111349 then you can upload image on another website and pass link here.

Comment: @user3111349 FB is blocked here

Comment: what do you recommend so I can show you the screenshot? Don't the explanations I gave you enough to understand the issue?